# Install Chocolatey using TFS build

Tags: tfs, chocolatey

I would like to silently install chocolatey on a series of test agents, and I'm trying to use a TFS build to do so. I have a build step that uses the "Run Powershell on Remote Machines" task. This in turn invokes the ps1 to install chocolatey, from `https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1`, and I supply the powershell switches as documented on the chocolatey website:

```
-NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

When I run the build, I receive this error:

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.

What am I doing wrong? Seems odd that the chocolatey installer required user interaction, I think the whole point of chocolately was silent installs?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I'm using TFS 15.112.26301.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have wrong settings in task "PowerShell on Target Machines". Follow the steps below:

1. Create a .ps1 file on the target machine and specify the text below:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object
>   System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

2. In "PowerShell on Target Machines" task, specify the location of the .ps1 file just created.
3. Queue the build.

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: hmm, bit confused - you've redacted the "Target Machines" part of the task name in the screenshot. Why? Are you actually running it on the build agent, not the remote machine?

Comment: I'm afraid I get this error message: Deployment status for machine 'KIWIINTCLM2:5985' : 'Failed'
Deployment failed on machine 'KIWIINTCLM2:5985' with following message : 'A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.'

Comment: What I've redacted is my server machine name, which is private. Do you run your build agent under interactive mode? Try to run configure it run as service to see whether the issue can be solved: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode

Comment: Are you able to get it work when you run the build agent as service?

Comment: Hi Cece...sorry for the slow response. The build agent is running as a service, yes... although I can't see how the build agent's properties make a difference. The powershell is running on the remote machine, not the build agent. It must be something to do with how the "Execute Powershell on Remote machine" works, how the listener on the remote machine is configured...

Comment: Do you specify the scope? What's the result if you run a the simple script?

Comment: @SimonGreen Do you try my steps? If you run the script directly on the target machine, what result will you get?

Comment: When I fixed this bug (had to do a local install using a downloaded copy of the chocolatey .nuget package), it worked as expected (in VSTS, using HTTPS for the Run PowerShell on Target Machines step): https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1560

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong? Seems odd that the chocolatey installer
>   required user interaction, I think the whole point of chocolately was
>   silent installs?

Typically it goes fully silent, unless there is something (like a proxy) that requires input. It would be best to determine what might be causing the issue by running the install directly on the machine and seeing what happens.

#### Details

The install.ps1 [passes over](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org/blob/9a78db34de3931e6652c84f9f21b3b79f5ec5995/chocolatey/Website/Install.ps1#L247) to [chocolateyInstall.ps1](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/nuget/chocolatey/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1), which calls [chocolateySetup.psm1](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/nuget/chocolatey/tools/chocolateysetup.psm1).

As you look over that script, you may notice that the install.ps1 uses `Write-Output`, but that psm1 uses `Write-Host` in some places. This may or may not cause issues, but it's unlikely given that the script works fine with PowerShell DSC.

So it could be a few things:

- Make sure whatever runs that script has Administrator privileges, otherwise you will get an access denied error (unless you specify a different Chocolatey installation location).
- Make sure you are not getting hit by needing to put in proxy credentials (which is fixed by the Offline Recommendation below).
- Make sure you are not getting hit with not being able to access internet resources (which is also fixed by using offline resources).
- It could be something else causing a popup, like needing to install .NET 4.x. Recommend you have the latest .NET Framework in the 4.x series installed prior to installing Chocolatey.

#### Offline Recommendation

The best recommendation we can give - don't use the internet for any part of this script. If you want reliability, you should have everything internal. That includes the install.ps1 script you are going to use for Chocolatey and the chocolatey.nupkg itself.

Take a read over at https://chocolatey.org/install#completely-offline-install to understand our recommendations.